# Swift - NSMenu closes when clicking outside of menu

Tags: macos, swift, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

so i have a simple NSMenu. It is attached to a Status Item Button.
When i click the Button it pops Open.
Now my Problem is that as soon as i click outside of the NSMenu, it closes. How can i avoid that ?
I did try many things but cant get that to work.

The reason i need that is that when the user clicks something in the NSMenu, another window opens, and while this window is open i also want the NSMenu to stay open. But it just does not work.

I feel like its impossible.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you even _want_ to keep it open? Most people will expect it to close when you click outside; in fact, it's the normal way to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to create a custom view that pops up but something that could be done natively with just NSMenu.